# Automate NSG rule creation for NSGs within azure: Type error from Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup

Tags: azure, powershell, object, null, azure-nsg

I am trying to write a script to automate creating NSG rules for our production NSGs. I am pretty sure I have something close to working but the issue I run into is that the `Get-AZNetworkSecurityGroup` command returns a string and so I cant feed it into the `Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig` command.

```
Import-Module Az.network
Connect-AzAccount
$tcpports = @(22,53,80,135,137,161,427,443,515,548,5060,5480,5985,5986,5989,9100,9443)
$udpports = @(53,161,427,515,548)
$solservers = #Server IP here
$file = Import-Csv C:\Users\temp\Downloads\AzureNSGs.csv

foreach ($NSG in $file){
$RGname=$NSG.'RESOURCE GROUP'
$nsgname=$NSG.NAME
$NSGObj = Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup | Where-Object -Property Name -Like $RGname | Select-Object -Property Name
$name = "AllowSolarWinds"
    if($NSGObj){
    $name = $name + 1 
    $NSGObj | Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $name -NetworkSecurityGroup $NSGObj -Protocol Icmp -SourceAddressPrefix $solservers -DestinationPortRange "*" -Priority 555 
    $NSGObj | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup 
    }
}
```

Whenever I run this I get two kinds of returns. It either looks like it ran successfully with no errors but the rule is never created in azure. Or powershell spits out one of the following errors.

```
Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig : Cannot bind argument to parameter 'NetworkSecurityGroup' because it is null.
```

or

```
Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig : Cannot bind parameter 'NetworkSecurityGroup'. Cannot convert the value of type "System.String" to type 
"Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSNetworkSecurityGroup".
```

Comment: MS documentation provides examples by piping 'Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup' into 'Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig'. It looks like you are filtering the 'Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup' after collecting the lot, try definig '-name' and '-resourceGroup'. It returns a custom PS object, see here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.network/get-aznetworksecuritygroup?view=azps-9.4.0#outputs
-- I have just noticed the issue. After your filtering, you are using 'Select-Object'. I believe THIS is causing the output to be a string instead of the expected custom object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I got the same error like below:***

[image]

To resolve the error, try to modify the code like below:

```
Connect-AzAccount
Import-Module Az.network
$tcpports = @(22,53,80,135,137,161,427,443,515,548,5060,5480,5985,5986,5989,9100,9443)
$udpports = @(53,161,427,515,548)
$solservers = "112.121.61.196"
$file = Import-Csv C:\Users\v-khanimran\Downloads\AzureNSGs.csv

foreach ($NSG in $file){
$RGname=$NSG.RESOURCEGROUPNAME
$nsgname=$NSG.NAME
$NSGObj =Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup -Name $nsgname -ResourceGroupName $RGname
#Get-AzNetworkSecurityGroup | Where-Object {$_.Name -Like $nsgname} | Select-Object -Property Name
$name = "AllowSolarWinds"
    if($NSGObj){
    $name = $name + 1 
    $NSGObj | Add-AzNetworkSecurityRuleConfig -Name $name  -Protocol Icmp -SourceAddressPrefix $solservers -DestinationPortRange  "*" -SourcePortRange "*" -DestinationAddressPrefix "*" -Priority 555 -Access Allow -Direction Inbound 
    
    $NSGObj | Set-AzNetworkSecurityGroup 
    }
}
```

***Output:***

[image]

In the portal NSG rule got added successfully like below:

[image]